# ¿Error al conectar a un api rest en un dispositivo fisico en ionic?

Tags: android, angular, ionic, http, cordova

Estoy haciendo una app utilizando Ionic 6 y angular 10, cuando pruebo el proyecto en el navegador conecta perfectamente a la api rest, pero cuando ejecuto el comando de ionic prepare andoid y  cordova ionic build android me genera la una carpeta para debugguear desde android pero la aplicación no conecta a la api rest y me sale lo siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya agregue los siguientes permisos en el AndroidManifest.xlm

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y sigue sin conectarme.
En el servidor ya están configurados los Cors y si conecta cuando se hace una petición sencilla utilizando fetch desde javascript.
pero en un dispositivos físico no lo hace.
De antemano les agredesco su tiempo y muchas gracias por atención.

Comment: tengo ese probelmapero como puedo quitar el modo solo lectura en mis archivos?

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar en tu AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Luego en el network_security_config.xml que esta en resources/andoid/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">dominioDeLaApi.com</domain>
</domain-config>
```